# Factorplot with multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, data-analysis

This is the dataframe I am working with:

[image]
(only the first two years don't have data for country 69 I will fix this). `nkill` being the number of killed for that year summed from the original long form dataframe.

I am trying to do something similar to this plot:

[image: this plot]

However, with the country code as a hue. I know there are similar posts but none have helped me solve this, thank you in advance.

By Hue I mean that in the seaborn syntactical use [As pictured in this third picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxbVK.png). See in this example Hue creates a plot for every type of variable in that column. So if I had two country codes in the country column, for every year it would plot two bars (one for each country) side by side.

Comment: What do you mean by "with the country code as a hue"? Can you describe the plot you are trying to achieve? What is it supposed to look like in terms of bars and their color? Do you want several bars per year then? If so how should that be arranged?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just edited the question, let me know if that makes more sense but you're basically right, several bars per year, one for every country code in the country column

Comment: Ok, so this should work - just as in the example plot you link to. Where is the problem? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at the data it should be possible to directly use the `hue` argument.
But first you would need to create actual columns from the dataframe

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Then something like

```
sns.barplot(x = "year", y="nkill", hue="country", data=df)
```

should give you the desired plot.